# Array Pagination - Writing Math Equation

Tags: php, arrays, oop

My question is almost similar to my previous question which is related to Array Pagination.

If `$CurrentPage = 1` then I want `StartPage = 20`, if `$CurrentPage = 2` then `StartPage = 15`, if `CurrentPage = 3` then `StartPage = 10`, if `CurrentPage = 4` then `StartPage = 5`

Note the difference if 5 is due to number of rows per page, which may change. So in case its 10 and if `$CurrentPage = 1` then `StartPage = 20`, if `CurrentPage = 2` then `StartPage = 10`

I just want to know how I go about writing math equation for it
For example, I wrote something like this

```
    $RowsPerPage = 5;
    $StartPage = $RowsPerPage * ( RowsPerPage - $CurrentPage);
```

However, the above works only if `RowsPerPage` is set to 5.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
$StartPage = 20 - (($CurrentPage - 1) * $RowsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$RowsPerPage = 5;
$TotalPages = 20;
$StartPage = $TotalPages - ( ( $CurrentPage - 1 ) * $RowsPerPage );
```

This should do what you want.